# Twig nl2br filter not working on entity

Tags: php, symfony, twig, template-engine, nl2br

I have an Address entity with a __toString() method like this :

```
public function __toString() {
    $result = $this->getStreet();

    if ($this->getStreet2())
        $result .= '\n' . $this->getStreet2();

    $result .= '\n' . $this->getZipCode().' '.$this->getCity();
    return $result;
}
```

In my template, I apply the [Twig nl2br filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/nl2br.html) on the entity :

```
{{ user.address|nl2br }}
```

but I still get the escaped \n :

**1107 West Adams Boulevard\n90007 Los Angeles, CA**

I tried using this string instead of the entity :

```
{{ "1107 West Adams Boulevard\n90007 Los Angeles, CA"|nl2br }}
```

And I get the expected result :

**1107 West Adams Boulevard**

**90007 Los Angeles, CA**

I also tried

```
{{ user.address|raw|nl2br }}
```

Which is not safe, but still doesn't work...
I've tried with Twig 1.8.0 and 1.9.0.

Any idea ?

Comment: Use `"\n"` instead of `'\n'` :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of having:

```
$result .= '\n' . $this->getZipCode().' '.$this->getCity();
```

try this:

```
$result .= "\n" . $this->getZipCode()." ".$this->getCity();
```

PHP will interpret escape characters in double quoted strings.

[This PHP Manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) might help.